# get group members separated by semicolon or only in same line

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

In PowerShell, I would like to get members of a group name in one line separated by semicolon or simply in one line output.

PS C:\Windows\ `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Hardware Drawing" | Select Name`

```
Name
----
Rusten, Brian
Kim, Calvin
```

I want above names in one line separated by semicolon or simply in one line

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use the `-expand` switch of the `Select-Object` cmdlet. Then use the `-join` operator. See also [about_join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847757.aspx):

```
(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Hardware Drawing" | Select -expand Name) -join ';'
```

Comment: Thank You Martin for the reply. it is working. Sorry for my late comment.

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider to accepting the answer.